# Trying to contain a field that uses UNIX_TIMESTAMP

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.3

I'm trying to convert the updated datetime column to a number. So I did this in my Containable behavior.

```
    $this->paginate = array(
        'limit'=>1,
        'fields'=>array(
            'id',
        ),
        'contain'=>array(
            'Image'=>array('fields'=>array(
                'id',
                'UNIX_TIMESTAMP(Image.updated) AS `rev`',
            ))
        )
    );
```

I get this data from Paginator

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [Receipt] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 19938
                )
            [Image] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 18143
                            [receipt_id] => 19938
                            [Image] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => Array
                                        (
                                            [rev] => 1357872726
                                        )

                                )

                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 18144
                            [receipt_id] => 19938
                            [Image] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => Array
                                        (
                                            [rev] => 1357872728
                                        )

                                )

                        )

                )

        )

)
```

For some reason `Image` is nested twice for each record. If I remove the UNIT_TIMESTAMP it gets the data correctly.

```
    $this->paginate = array(
        'limit'=>1,
        'fields'=>array(
            'id',
        ),
        'contain'=>array(
            'Image'=>array('fields'=>array(
                'id',
                'updated',
            ))
        )
    );
```

Output

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [Receipt] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 19938
                )

            [Image] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 18143
                            [updated] => 2013-01-10 21:52:06
                            [receipt_id] => 19938
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 18144
                            [updated] => 2013-01-10 21:52:08
                            [receipt_id] => 19938
                        )

                )

        )

)
```

Any idea why Cake is going this when I add an expression to a field?

Answer (score 1):

You can try using [virtual fields](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/virtual-fields.html):

```
public function __construct($id = false, $table = null, $ds = null) {
    parent::__construct($id, $table, $ds);
    $this->virtualFields['name'] = sprintf(
        'UNIX_TIMESTAMP(%s.updated) AS %s.rev', $this->alias, $this->alias
    );
}
```

Not sure if my notation is right, give it a try, I haven't tested it.

Comment: True, didn't realize you're trying it on an associated model.